# What is the best way to label placeholder call-to-actions?

Tags: forms, input, input-fields, text, placeholder

I'm creating a search input where the user can search for: restaurants, dishes, and cuisines. I was wondering when it comes to placeholder text what is the most proper way to label this call-to-action?

I've seen sites word them in sentence format as so:

***Search for restaurants, dishes, and cuisines***

and others where its more broken down:

***Search restaurants, cuisines, dishes***

Then there is the question of capitalization. Should topics for search be capitalized in order to stand out more to the user?

***Search Restaurants, Cuisines, Dishes***

Comment: Is there a label for your search input field? And if so, what is the text for it?

Comment: don't confuse labels and placeholders. They serve different purposes. As to your specific question, there's no one right answer to it. It's mainly a writing style question and would be dictated by the rest of the writing style on your particular web site.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really think it matters if you capitalize your placeholder words or not. If you want to be consistent I would suggest going with:

***Search Restaurants, Cuisines, Dishes***

Also as far as proper wording check out [image]

Yelp, which is heavily search based, does not necessarily honor any consistency, as their search placeholders embodies all different criteria and capitalization of words.